# Not propagating clicks

Tags: java, android

When I click an Android button the Android's Software Keys are shown (hidden before) instead of firing the onClick() method for the actual button that I click.

I have two methods for showing or hiding the system UI:

1.

```
    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and 2:

```
/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And I also have another method which a switch to get the onClick() event on buttons

```
public void onClick(View v) { switch() { } }
```

Is it possible to fix this behaviour and when I click the actual button will be fired and the System UI will be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround to overcome this behaviour until you have both touch listener and also a click listener inside the same view. Try using

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

instead. Add the below code before `setcontentview()` method.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: I tried to comment the first 2 snippets and insert the method's contents inside the third snipped but still I get the same behaviour. Where should I put the code you pasted?

Comment: Thanks, at least its nicer now.